# Activation codes

Tags: java, activation

I am not sure what shall i put as Title for this Question, But I am here looking for help.

I work in a company which makes desktop based application on CORE JAVA Platform.
We provide an ACTIVATION CODE to activate our software. 
The concept of activation is -

> > User enters the Activation code --> software hits our server and download all the required files --> activation completed.
> >
> > Once in a day, our software hits our server to check if the activation code has been expired.

Problem-
We have a new client which doesn't have a regular internet connection. Somehow they agreed to provide internet connection for one time-

> > User enters the Activation code --> software hits our server and download all the required files --> activation completed.
> >
> > but after that no internet connection. I can stop the software to check with server about expiry Date of activation code.
> >     But the problem with me is-
> >
> > 1) How do I check whether the Activation code has actually expired? ( Activation code is valid for 1 year only)
> >
> > 2) If after expiry If user enters a new Activation code, how do I check this is a valid activation code with 1 year validity?

Answer (score 1):

1) you can store the registration date and compare it against the system date. of course then users can temper with the date. I used to have some software that always stored the last date it had seen, and if one moved the date to the past, it complained and insta-expired. you could do something like this but of course it's never as safe as talking to a server.

2) create a format for your activation key that contains a new key as well as the previous key. so the first key is, say, A, which is good for talking to a server and checking if A is okay. A new key might look like AB meaning "I replace A, add another year of activation, and am called B, so in a year, we'll need a key like BC". You'll have to think a bit about how to encode this securely, but I'm pretty confident it can work (for example, you can encrypt B with A, then B can only be used on a machine with activation code A).